# ERROR: relation "stg_data_bt_sur" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I've created a table in postgresql which is OK and I'm able to do select/insert using SQL manager tool or Navicat Lite tool.
But, when I'm trying to make simple select from LINUX(ubuntu) I have following message:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from stg_data_brest_surgery;
ERROR:  relation "stg_data_brest_surgery" does not exist
STATEMENT:  select count(*) from stg_data_brest_surgery;
ERROR:  relation "stg_data_brest_surgery" does not exist.
```

I also used table name with double quotes -  same result.
Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right database? Try a `\d` from the `psql` prompt and see if the tables look familiar, also have a look at what `\l` says. Your prompt indicates that you're in the `postgres` database but you probably want to be somewhere else.

Comment: I think @muistooshort nailed it. `postgres` is the default maintainance db. If you start `psql` without naming a database, you end up there.

Comment: The \d says: No relations found.

Comment: The \l shows:         List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding
-----------+----------+----------
 CNCRRPTDB | postgres | UTF8
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8
 template0 | postgres | UTF8
 template1 | postgres | UTF8
 test      | postgres | UTF8
(5 rows)

Comment: my tables in CNCRRPTDB. How to change location? use CNCRRPTD?

Comment: Erwin how to start with my db which is CNCRRPTDB? ./psq -u postgres -d cncrrptdb? is this correct?

Comment: Thanks to all. I did use default connection instead of specific DB.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the schema isn't in your search path,  Try `\dn` to list namespaces and then you can either add the schema like:

```
 SELECT * from "schema"."table";
```

Or you can set your search path:

```
 SET search_path="schema";
 SELECT * FROM "table";
 RESET search_path;
```

Comment: When I did the \d and \l, everything I want to look at shows up.  It was only when I had to add the schema to the from clause that worked.  Thanks!